# Video scaling vs Display scaling

Tags: fpga, display, video, scaling

I am going to start a project in FPGA and "graphical screen" scaling. I am still in the "reading-the-material-phase".

- Are there any differences between video-scaling and display(e.g. Windows Desktop)-scaling?
  Video scaling is using Bi-linear,Bi-cubic etc. IEEE got a lot of articles related to hardware implementation of video-scaling. But I have not found anything related to display (desktop) scaling.
- If I have multiple displays and want to share the same computer-desktop, but the displays are using different ports (VGA, HDMI, display-port) and the displays are of different size. What kind of scaling algorithm are they(Microsoft,Apple etc.) using as standard to adapt an application for each display/screen
- When I want to resize a screen from e.g 720x480 —> 1280x720, what type of standard scaling algorithms are used?(bilinear, bi-cubic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling can be done by the application, monitor or GPU driver as permitted by the operating system.

http://tanalin.com/en/articles/lossless-scaling/

Answer (score 0):

What Windows calls "display scaling" or "DPI scaling" is a setting that gets sent to the applications rendering to the display as a hint to encourage them to scale the pixel positions of things drawn in the app. This is to enable the use of small, high DPI screens without icons and text appearing unusably tiny.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2015/12/08/display-scaling-in-windows-10/

Monitors can use various scaling algorithms, some of the more expensive ones will offer you a choice.